# Restoring data after upgrading Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise

I'm trying to upgrade from Cassandra to the latest Datastax Enterprise and everything went fine except the fact I can't get my data back.

Basically, I had a clean cassandra after the upgrade, then I recreated the schema and trying to somehow link the files that are left from old db to the new db.

That's what I have right now in `/var/lib/cassandra/data/wowch` directory for example:

```
drwxr-x---  4 cassandra cassandra 4.0K Feb 27 13:05 users-247834809d2011e58d82b7a748b1d9c2/
drwxr-xr-x  2 cassandra cassandra 4.0K Feb 27 18:53 users-f41a5300dd5611e58bc7b7a748b1d9c2/
```

As I get, the older directory is what was in the db before the upgrade. It contains some db files:

```
total 144K
drwxr-x---  4 cassandra cassandra 4.0K Feb 27 13:05 ./
drwxr-x--- 60 cassandra cassandra  20K Feb 27 14:35 ../
drwxr-x---  2 cassandra cassandra 4.0K Dec  7 21:21 backups/
-rwxr-x---  2 cassandra cassandra   51 Jan 20 00:05 ma-46-big-CompressionInfo.db*
-rwxr-x---  2 cassandra cassandra  828 Jan 20 00:05 ma-46-big-Data.db*
-rwxr-x---  2 cassandra cassandra   10 Jan 20 00:05 ma-46-big-Digest.crc32*
-rwxr-x---  2 cassandra cassandra   16 Jan 20 00:05 ma-46-big-Filter.db*
-rwxr-x---  2 cassandra cassandra   83 Jan 20 00:05 ma-46-big-Index.db*
-rwxr-x---  2 cassandra cassandra 4.9K Jan 20 00:05 ma-46-big-Statistics.db*
-rwxr-x---  2 cassandra cassandra   92 Jan 20 00:05 ma-46-big-Summary.db*
-rwxr-x---  2 cassandra cassandra   92 Jan 20 00:05 ma-46-big-TOC.txt*
-rwxr-x---  2 cassandra cassandra   43 Feb 12 15:05 ma-47-big-CompressionInfo.db*
-rwxr-x---  2 cassandra cassandra   41 Feb 12 15:05 ma-47-big-Data.db*
-rwxr-x---  2 cassandra cassandra   10 Feb 12 15:05 ma-47-big-Digest.crc32*
-rwxr-x---  2 cassandra cassandra   16 Feb 12 15:05 ma-47-big-Filter.db*
-rwxr-x---  2 cassandra cassandra   20 Feb 12 15:05 ma-47-big-Index.db*
-rwxr-x---  2 cassandra cassandra 4.5K Feb 12 15:05 ma-47-big-Statistics.db*
-rwxr-x---  2 cassandra cassandra   92 Feb 12 15:05 ma-47-big-Summary.db*
-rwxr-x---  2 cassandra cassandra   92 Feb 12 15:05 ma-47-big-TOC.txt*
-rwxr-x---  2 cassandra cassandra   43 Feb 12 16:05 ma-48-big-CompressionInfo.db*
-rwxr-x---  2 cassandra cassandra  169 Feb 12 16:05 ma-48-big-Data.db*
-rwxr-x---  2 cassandra cassandra   10 Feb 12 16:05 ma-48-big-Digest.crc32*
-rwxr-x---  2 cassandra cassandra   16 Feb 12 16:05 ma-48-big-Filter.db*
-rwxr-x---  2 cassandra cassandra   20 Feb 12 16:05 ma-48-big-Index.db*
-rwxr-x---  2 cassandra cassandra 4.9K Feb 12 16:05 ma-48-big-Statistics.db*
-rwxr-x---  2 cassandra cassandra   92 Feb 12 16:05 ma-48-big-Summary.db*
-rwxr-x---  2 cassandra cassandra   92 Feb 12 16:05 ma-48-big-TOC.txt*
-rwxr-x---  1 cassandra cassandra   31 Dec  7 21:26 manifest.json*
drwxr-x---  3 cassandra cassandra 4.0K Feb 27 13:05 snapshots/
```

I tried to copy all the stuff from here to the `users-f41a5300dd5611e58bc7b7a748b1d9c2/` directory and run `nodetool repair` or `nodetool refresh -- wowch users` but had no success — the data is still not loaded.

Did I forget something? What is the right way of doing it and how to get the data back?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version of Cassandra/DSE you were previously running you may need to run a `nodetool upgradesstables`.  You can see the documentation here.

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/tools/toolsUpgradeSstables.html

Comment: Is there anything in the C* logs that helps?  (/var/log/Cassandra/system.log most likely)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you've run into [this issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-5202) but without more info I can't say for sure.

You also haven't provided info on which version you started with and ended. A little more info would be very helpful. Can you also clarify - are you upgrading from community Cassandra to DSE? I couldn't tell from the way your question was worded.

Stuff to check: Do you have the token assignments from the old version? I didn't use vnodes and I found that I had to manually set initial_token in cassandra.yaml after a backup/restore of my cluster. Make sure that cassandra owns all of the dirs and files. After you import the schema, stop DSE and then empty the contents of the commitlog directory. move your data if necessary into the new folders and then restart DSE. Hope this helps.

Comment: yes, I updated from community Cassandra (2.2) to DSE (4.8).

Comment: and I entirely copied the configuration file from the old installation to the new one, so the initial token is not the case here (moreover, I don't have it specified, it's left as default)

Comment: if you have the output of  'nodetool ring' from the original cluster, you will see the token ranges for the nodes which were assigned automatically. On your restored system, you'll have to edit cassandra.yaml on each node and manually assign the same tokens. Otherwise the nodes won't know which part of the token ring they're responsible for when the partitioner tries to query the ring.